# How to create a grouped cumulative frequency graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumulative-frequency

I'm working with a dataset of elemental concentrations, and I want to compare the cumulative frequency graphs of elemental concentrations in two places, like I did using plot() in
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp2Ln.png), but with ggplot. Here is a dummy dataset

```
df<-data.frame("Zone"=c(rep("A",10),rep("B",9)),"Con"=c(rnorm(10,5,2),rnorm(9,7,2.5)))
```

I've managed to make a cumulative frequency graph for both zones together in this clumsy way:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=cumsum(rep(1,19)),y=sort(Con)))+geom_point()
```

But I can't figure out how to make it for both zones separately.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd like to use `stat_ecdf` from ggplot2:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Con, color = Zone)) + stat_ecdf(geom = "point")
```